# Hive how to convert a float to scientific notation

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata

I am trying to compare result from a hive query to output from teradata database.
I am having trouble in comparing float and double numbers as they are converted to scientific notation by bteq.

An example of this is :
-0.029320776 in hive is converted to 2.93207760000000E-002 in bteq.

Is there any way I can convert the hive output to same format?

Comment: What kind of trouble are you having? Is that a precision issue, a string comparison issue, etc?

Comment: It is a string comparison issue.As formats are different string comparison fails.Note that I cannot change the comparison function due to some constraints.